# SQL On Server: Saving Query Statements to a File

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**What I am trying to do**: Save the exact queries that MySQL is using to populate data on my website. For this I want to save the ex: 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X > 2' that is requested from my database into a text file on the server. To avoid the "Why do you need this?" question, a project for a databases class is asking me to research exactly how a database is gathering data and what better place to learn that than my own website?

**What I have tried**: I looked into the SPOOL command, but that is only for Oracle systems from what I have gathered. Looking in to the Tee command, I could append query results to a file.

**Why my attempts have not been successful**: The solution cannot be through SQL queries as I am not having exact control of how the database is filled. The database created from a connector called the IMDB-Connector and is populated when I pass a query into the API. With this implementation I am looking for something along the lines of an "Enable Logging of Queries in fill X.log"

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to log the queries used to access a certain MySQL database hosted on a server?

Long time reader of stackoverflow but first time querying the human database; will edit the question if not adequately explained.

Comment: you can enable the query log in mysql, but note that this is highly insecure on a production system, as it'll log the literal query text, which will include things like passwords

Comment: Luckily this this not a production system but more of a 'learn a bit more on how this specific system is working' setup. I have enabled the logs, ran the functionality of my website, and then turned off the logs. Thank you for the security note as such blurbs of wisdom are what can keep a person searching for this from having such vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SET profiling = 1;` to turn the mySql profiler on

Then you can use `SHOW PROFILES` to list recently run SQL Statements

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: This is currently the accepted answer and I will attempt to use this when I get back to my main machine. Thank you for the rapid and well-explained response.